# Go countdown timer in loop

Tags: algorithm, go, timer

I currently have this code that is trying to count the elapsed time to trigger a certain condition. (pseudo):

```
timeDelay = 900000 // time.Microsecond
for {
   // if a certain something happens, start a counting (time)
   if (certainSomething) {
      startTime = time.Now();

      if !prevTime.IsZero() {
        // add the time elapsed time to timeTick
        diffTime = time.Since(prevTime)
        timeTick = timeTick + diffTime
      }

      prevTime = startTime
   }

   if (timeTick < timeDelay) { // lessThan()
      // still has not reached target count (time elapsed)
      fmt.Println("Not Yet")
      // we dont want to get to the end of the loop yet
      continue
   }

   if (timeTick > timeDelay) { // greaterThan()
      // has finally reached the target count (time elapsed)
      fmt.Println("Yes! Finally")
      // yes the delay has been reached lets reset the time
      // and if `thisHappened` is triggered again, lets start counting again
      timeTick = time.Duration(0 * time.Microsecond)
   }

   // function shouldn't be called if the elapsed amount
   //      of time required has not yet been reached
   iShouldOnlyBeCalledWhenDelayHasBeenReached();
}
```

I'm also using these as helper functions (actual code)

```
func lessThan(diff time.Duration, upper int) bool {
    return diff < time.Duration(upper)*time.Microsecond && diff != 0
}

func greaterThan(diff time.Duration, upper int) bool {
    return diff > time.Duration(upper)*time.Microsecond
}
```

But, I'm just not comfortable of how I'm doing it. I shouldn't be counting up, right? I should be counting down... I'm just confused and need help on what approach I should use.

What I want to happen:
1. A countdown from `timeDelay` to 0 starts when `certainSomething` happens.
2. Do not call `iShouldOnlyBeCalledWhenDelayHasBeenReached` until the countdown hits 0.
3. This should all happen inside a loop, a server loop receiving packets to be exact.

My question:
1. What should I do to achieve that countdown style?

Thank you, any suggestion or example code would help a lot.

> Note: There are other functions in the loop. Doing other things. This is the main loop. I can't make it `Sleep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a channel to let you know when you've exceeded the time.

Here's an example [on play](http://play.golang.org/p/_fs4i3oqxy)

It has an added benefit that in the select statement, you can have other channels for other purposes.  For example,if you are doing other work in this loop, you could also spawn that work in a goroutine and have it send the result back on another channel.
Then you exit after `timeDelay` or when other work completes, or whatever.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    certainSomething := true // will cause time loop to repeat

    timeDelay := 900 * time.Millisecond // == 900000 * time.Microsecond

    var endTime <-chan time.Time // signal for when timer us up

    for {
        // if a certain something happens, start a timer
        if certainSomething && endTime == nil {
            endTime = time.After(timeDelay)
        }
        select {
        case <-endTime:
            fmt.Println("Yes Finally!")
            endTime = nil
        default:
            fmt.Println("not yet")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond) // simulate work
            continue
        }

        // function shouldn't be called if the elapsed amount
        //      of time required has not yet been reached
        iShouldOnlyBeCalledWhenDelayHasBeenReached() // this could also just be moved to the <- endtime block above
    }
}

func iShouldOnlyBeCalledWhenDelayHasBeenReached() {
    fmt.Println("I've been called")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a game as you say, it sounds to me that you:

- want to do X amount of work
- if the time of work exceeds `delay` amount, stop work and loop again

If this is the case, then you have a few options and patterns.

[time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) come to mind.

I like the cleanliness of `time.After` in a select statement.  No channels or goroutines needed to handle it.

This pattern also has the added benefit of using goroutines for your main game logic.

On play: http://play.golang.org/p/FIiUJ0CHZz

Change the `time.After()` to see it in action.

```
func main() {

    for {

        // creating a new channel on each loop will allow the
        // GC to collect any game stuff that completes after the timeout.
        done := make(chan int)

        // main game func, doing your other stuff.
        // since this is in a goroutine, it won't block
        // and we can check the state in the select.
        go func(){

            // complicated logic here!
            //

            // you must issue an "I am done!"
            done <- 1
        }()

        // this will block the for loop until a timeout occurs
        select {
            case <- done:
                continue
            case <- time.After(1000 * time.Nanosecond):
                iShouldOnlyBeCalledWhenDelayHasBeenReached()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that using `time.After` in a for loop can lead to unexpectedly high memory usage if the duration of a for cycle is significantly lower than the timeout. The timer created with `time.After` is not garbage collected until it expires.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make the routine sleep, you should use the `time.Time.Add` and `time.Time.After` (or `time.Time.Before`) functions.

Something along theses lines

```
package main         

import "time"        

func main() {        

    var d = 1000 * time.Microsecond
    var t = time.Now().Add(d)

    for {            
        if time.Now().Before(t) {
            continue 
        }            

        do_something()
    }                
}
```

Or deport the method you have to run after a certain time in a routine that you can make sleep:

```
package main         

import "time"        

func main() {

    var d = 1000 * time.Microsecond

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(d)
        do_something()
    }()
}
```

Comment: Just to note, there are other functions running in the loop. I can't make it sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Time is up!")
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/LTEKzvJUMi)

Comment: Just to note, there are other functions running in the loop. I can't make it sleep.

Comment: @majidarif Run them in goroutines then. It is the way, you deal with concurrency in Go.